# Ways of arranging $k$ cards in a deck of $N$ cards

Tags: combinatorics

I have a deck of $N$ cards numbered $1, \ldots N$. I want to count the number of ways that $k$ cards may appear in order. For example, if $k = 3$, I want to count the number of ways that of having a deck such that card $1$ appears before card $2$ appears before card $3$. The remaining $N - 3$ cards can be arranged arbitrarily. Note: card $1$ must appear before card $2$, but there can be $\geq 0$ cards inbetween them.

I am struggling to start on this question - I thought perhaps I could apply stars and bars, but I wasn't sure how to guarantee the ordering.

Comment: There are $k!$ ways to arrange those $k$ cards, and only one of those is in ascending order.

Comment: @DanielMathias So would the solution simply be $(N - k)!$ as that represents the number of ways of ordering the remaining? edit: Perhaps the question was not clear, I've since updated it

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need also to consider the $\binom{N}{k}$ ways to position the $k$ cards that you are interested in.

Comment: @DanielMathias Ah, ok. So there are $\binom N k$ ways to position $k$ cards with the deck. Within those positions, there is $1$ way where the $k$ are ascending. Finally, there are $(N - k)!$ ways to arrange the remaining cards. Thus, the final answer is $\binom N k \cdot (N -k)!$.

Comment: Yes, that is the number of ways to arrange a deck of $N$ cards such that a specific subset of $k$ cards appears in ascending order within deck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer from comments)

There is $1$ way to arrange $k$ cards in any specific order (ascending, in this case).

There are $\binom{N}{k}$ ways to position those $k$ cards within a deck of $N$ cards.

Finally, there are $(N-k)!$ ways to arrange the remaining cards.

The total is therefore:

$$\binom N k \cdot (N -k)!=\frac{N!}{k!}$$